# How to kill a running iPython process

Tags: python, macos, io, ipython

I'm using iPython to control some other equipment connected to my Mac. Most of the time it runs fine, but sometimes I gave a wrong command to the equipment, iPython is just hanging forever since it's waiting for a response but won't get one, so I need a way to kill the iPython process. `ctrl+c` doesn't do anything, it just prints a `^C` string on the screen. `ctrl+z` can get me out of iPython, but it doesn't seem to kill it, because when I restart iPython I can't re-establish the communication with the equipment. Eventually I had to restart my computer to get the two talking again.

Comment: PS, thanks for making me realize I still had IPython 2.1 instead of 2.2 on this computer. I guess I never notice the startup banner until something forces me to look at it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ctrl+z can get me out of iPython, but it doesn't seem to kill it, because when I restart iPython I can't re-establish the communication with the equipment. Eventually I had to restart my computer to get the two talking again.

Assuming you're using `bash` (the default shell for OS X), the ^Z turns it into a suspended background job, and you can use [job control](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) to kill it:

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
[2]+  Stopped                 ipython
$ kill %2

[2]+  Stopped                 ipython
$

[2]+  Terminated: 15          ipython
$
```

A couple of things to notice there:

- Usually the backgrounded program will be job 1, but you can't rely on that. Look at the `[2]+ Stopped`; that tells you that it's job 2, so you need `kill %2`, not `kill %1`.

  - (I deliberately put another job in the background to make it `2` for demonstration purposes.)
  - If you're not sure which job you want to kill, use the `jobs` command to list them all.
  - Or you can use `%ipython`, which refers to the first job whose name starts with `ipython`.
  - Or `%%`, which means the "current" job—if you haven't done anything since the `^Z`, that'll be `ipython`, but if you've done a bunch of other stuff since then and aren't sure if you affected job control, be careful.
- Although the `kill %2` kills the task immediately, `bash` may not recognize that until the next prompt; notice that I had to hit `return` an extra time before seeing the `Terminated` message.

  - In some situations, you'll need to use the `wait` command.
- If `IPython` is very badly hung and not responding to signals properly, use `kill -9 %2`.
- If you hit `^Z` by mistake and don't want to kill the job, use `fg %2` instead of `kill %2` to get back into `IPython`.
- If you want to let `IPython` run in the background while you do other things, use `bg %2` instead of `kill %2`. (You can always `fg` or `kill` it later (or `disown` it, or various other things—see the linked guide.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Terminal find out the process id using the "top" command. It is the PID column, and under the COMMAND column you will see IPython, or something similar.
Them run `kill -9 PID`